# Why Apple In-Ear headphones do not work with iPod Shuffle 3rd Generation?

Tags: iphone, ipod, headphones

Nowadays I use one Apple In-Ear headphones with iPhone. I tried the same with iPod 3rd Generation but surprisingly it does not work.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at **Compatibility** *section* in the [Apple In-Ear Headphones with Remote and Mic](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/ME186LL/A/apple-in-ear-headphones-with-remote-and-mic) webpage, the **iPod Shuffle 3rd Generation** is not listed, and therefore is why they do not work with that device. The only **iPod shuffle** listed is the **iPod shuffle 4th Generation**.

---

[image]

Comment: I'm still curious about the details. How would you make it?

Comment: @KcFnMi, What details and how would you make it do what!? The iPod Shuffle 3rd Generation **is not a supported device** with that accessory!

Comment: Which thing is different in the In-Ear headphone compared to the original iPod Shuffle 3rd?